# Sqlite3 passing a variable into an open() method in php

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to achieve the following. When I open a page, a specific date is passed from jquery datepicker to this site. Now for this date I'm creating a directory, which works fine. In this directory I want to create a sqlite3 Database File, which has the date as a name. For example:

2107.db

But I can't seem to get the open() method to accept my variable. I'm kind of new to php and sqlite3, so if I'm doing something completly wrong, please feel free to tell me.

Thank you for your help!

```
chdir($datum);
$cwd = getcwd() . DS;
}

if(isset($_POST['datum']))  {

    $datum = $_POST['datum'];   
    $file = $datum . ".db"; 

    class MyDB extends SQLite3
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->open($datum);
        }
    }

    $db = new MyDB();

    $db->exec('CREATE TABLE mitarbeiter (VID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, vorname varchar(255),       nachname varchar (255), bereich varchar (255), stundenzahl varchar (10))');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass the variable as parameter for the MyDB class.

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct($dbName)
    {
         $this->open($dbName);
    }
}
```

And then create the database with this

```
$db = new MyDB($datum);
```

This is probably because the class can't see the variable that you declared outside of it.